# how to reference columns in sql server connection in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to translate some perl code into C# and I'm having some trouble with the following.

After establishing a sql server connection and executing the select statement, how do I reference the different elements in the table columns.  For example, in Perl it looks like:

```
  my $dbh = DBI -> connect( NAME, USR, PWD )
            or die "Failed to connect to database: " . DBI->message;

  my $dbname = DB_NAME;
  my $dbschema = DB_SCHEMA;
  my $sql = qq{select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,...
             from $dbname.$dbschema.package p
             join $dbname.$dbschema.package_download pd on p.package_id = pd.package_id
             join $dbname.$dbschema.download d on pd.download_id = d.download_id
            where p.package_name = '$package'
              --and ds.server_address like 'tcp/ip'
            order by a,b,c,d,..};

  my $sth = $dbh -> prepare( $sql )
   or die "Failed to prepare statement: " . $dbh->message;

  $sth -> execute()
   or die "Failed to execute statement: " . $sth->message;

  #now to go through each row in result table

  while ( @data = $sth->fetchrow_array() )
  { 
    print "$data[0]";
    # If source server FTP is not already open, make new FTP
    if ( $data[0] != $src_id )
    {
        if ( $src_ftp )
        { $src_ftp -> quit; }
        $src_ftp = make_ftp( $data[1], $data[2], $data[3], $data[18], $data[19], $data[20] );
        $src_id = $data[0];
    } 
  }
```

so far I've got it down to

```
string db =  NAME;
        string myConnectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;" + "Initial Catalog=" + db + "User id=" + ODBC_USR + "Password=" + PWD
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);

     string myInsertQuery = "select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,...
             from $dbname.$dbschema.package p
             join $dbname.$dbschema.package_download pd on p.package_id = pd.package_id
             join $dbname.$dbschema.download d on pd.download_id = d.download_id
            where p.package_name = '$package'
              --and ds.server_address like 'tcp/ip'
            order by a,b,c,d,..";

     SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myInsertQuery);
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCommand.Connection.Close();
```

but how do I reference the columns like data[0] and data[1] in C#.  Sorry I'm new to both languages so my background is severely lacking.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could reference your column directly by its **column name** or by **numeric order** (it starts with 0 as the first column) either through a `DataTable`, `DataSet`, `DataReader` or a specific `DataRow`.
For the sake of example i'll use a DataTable here and I will name it as `dt` and let's say we want to reference the first row then you could reference it with the following Syntax/Format:

```
dt[RowNumber]["ColumnName or Column Number"].ToString();
```

For example:

```
dt[0]["a"].ToString();
```

Or by number the first column with be 0 like:

```
dt[0][0].ToString();
```

And use `Parameters` by the way because without which it would be susceptible to [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Here's a more complete code below:

```
 string db =  NAME;
 string myConnectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;" + "Initial Catalog=" + db + "User id=" + ODBC_USR + "Password=" + PWD

 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
      string mySelectQuery = @"SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,...
         FROM package p
         JOIN package_download pd on p.package_id = pd.package_id
         join download d on pd.download_id = d.download_id
        WHERE p.package_name = @PackageName
        AND ds.server_address LIKE 'tcp/ip%'
        ORDER by a,b,c,d";

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(mySelectQuery, connection))
            {

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PackageName", txtPackage.Text);

                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(dt);         
                        if (dt.Rows.Count>0) // Make sure there is something in your DataTable
                         {
                           String aVal = dt[0]["a"].ToString();
                           String bVal = dt[0]["b"].ToString();
                           // You'll be the one to fill up
                         }                                                          
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

I change your `LIKE 'tcp/ip'` to `LIKE 'tcp/ip%'` by the way which is the more appropriate one of using `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ado.net entity data table to reference the tables in your sql server. I don't know if you're asking exactly this but it may help. because direct referencing to sql server is not possible as far as i know.